# Where to download and how to configure php_print.dll for PHP Version 5.5.12

Tags: php-extension, php-5.5, php-printer

I installed the wampserver 2.5 version.

I need use the php extension of pinter.dll on php 5.5.12 to send infomration to thermal printer.

But when I download the extension from:

```
https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/printer/0.1.0-dev/php_printer-0.1.0-dev-5.5-ts-vc11-x86.zip
```

and put in it to PHP "`ext`" folder and add the "`printer.default_printer=PHP_INI_ALL
extension=php_printer.dll`" into  `php.ini` and then restart server, It still does not work.

Cannot find it on phpinfo, can't use "`function printer_open()`".

Any solutions are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"I put all files in "ext" fold of PHP into Windows\System32. And restart windows. It works" i found this is wrong answer.

What i did was that i saved the php.ini in the wrong folder. if open php.ini from the wamp menu, and then changing it, when save it, it would be saved directly to bin->apache->apache2.4.9->bin; actually,  the file need to change save into  bin->php->php5.5.12